# How are public and server controllers related to each other in MEAN.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean.io

Starting out with MEAN.io and they provide a sample "articles" model which is basically something like a blog post that comes with a title and body.

The example comes with an `index.html` file that displays a list of articles when you navigate to it. In this file, it calls a `find` method defined in the public controller as such

```
$scope.find = function() {      
  Articles.query(function(articles) {
     $scope.articles = articles;
  });      
};
```

I see a server controller that defines the following method

```
/**
 * List of Articles
 */
exports.all = function(req, res) {
  Article.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'name username').exec(function(err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(500, {
        error: 'Cannot list the articles'
      });
    }
    res.json(articles);
  });
};
```

When I add a constraint to the `find` method in the server controller, I can effectively define `where` filters to the query, which is reflected in the view.

Is there some connection between these two controllers that is implicitly handled by the framework? I can't find any information about how all of these are related.

Answer (score 0):

imho no.
if there was a filtering connection, code have to be like this

```
/**
 * List of Articles
 *  use GET /api/v1/articles?published=true to filter
 */
exports.all = function(req, res) {
  Article
        .find(req.query) //this is filtering!
        .sort('-created')
        .populate('user', 'name username')
        .exec(function(err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(500, {
        error: 'Cannot list the articles'
      });
    }
    res.json(articles);
  });
};
```

Comment: In that case what I am confused about is why a method that retrieves all of the articles from the database is written in two different places. Is this how it works in MEAN stack development?

Comment: Ok I think I understand how it works now. The server provides a RESTful API, and the front-end is somehow directing clients to the appropriate routes. I just need to spend some more time looking at how everything comes together.

Comment: yes, your are right. I think question was about how does the filter parameters are processed on api endpoint...